# Pandas: Row values as Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this

```
   CourseID                                        StudentID
0       100                                  (Student:1)=001
1       102                  (Student:1)=007;(Student:2)=006
2       103                                              NaN
3       106                                  (Student:1)=007
4       107                                              NaN
5       108  (Student:1)=005;(Student:2)=031;(Student:3)=011
```

I would like to construct the DataFrame as follows:

```
   CourseID      Student_1 Student_2 Student_3 
0       100            001     NaN         NaN       
1       102            007     006         NaN
2       103            NaN     NaN         NaN               
3       106            007     NaN         NaN        
4       107            NaN     NaN         NaN
5       108            005     031         011
```

Any suggestions on what is the best way to transform the DataFrame into the desired output?

Comment: do you know the number of students for each courseID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the desired output using the following code:

```
s = (df.StudentID.str.extractall("([^;]+?)=([^;]+)?")
       .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
       .set_index(0, append=True)[1]
       .unstack(level=1))

s.columns = s.columns.str.replace(
    ':', '_').str.replace('(', '').str.replace(')', '')

df = df.join(s)
```

Please let me know if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Let us try `str.get_dummies`, then modified the output and `join` it back

```
s=df.StudentID.str.get_dummies(';')
s=s.T.mul(pd.Series(s.columns.str.split('=').str[1],index=s.columns),axis=0).T
s.columns=s.columns.str.split('=').str[0].str.replace(':','_')
df=df.join(s)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I did try your code and exported the output to CSV but it's not given what I am looking for.

Here is the output in CSV Format:

CourseID,StudentID,(Student_1),(Student_1),(Student_1),(Student_2),(Student_2),(Student_3)
100,(Student:1)=001,001,,,,,
102,(Student:1)=007;(Student:2)=006,,,007,006,,
103,,,,,,,
106,(Student:1)=007,,,007,,,
107,,,,,,,
108,(Student:1)=005;(Student:2)=031;(Student:3)=011,,005,,,031,011